# OpenTBS pptx information does not update after slide delete

Tags: php, powerpoint, opentbs

I am using OpenTBS to delete slides from pptx file. I am using following to delete slides:

```
$pptx->PlugIn(OPENTBS_DELETE_SLIDES, $slidesDeleteArr);
```

The original file was of 42 slides and I have deleted all except slide 2. In the output pptx there is only slide 2 which is correct but when I see the properties of this pptx file, it still says 42 slides. Please see below screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PHkW.png)

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint stores the number of slides in the **docProps/app.xml** part:

```
<Slides>12</Slides>
```

I imagine PowerPoint only writes the number of slides when you add or delete a slide in the program. It sounds like you'll have to update that XML part to get an accurate slide count when you first open the file.